# Client side encryption of user data with user password

Tags: encryption, web-application, cryptography

I've narrowed down on a scheme that would allow my application to encrypt user data client side and transmit that data to the server, with no chance of our server ever being able to decrypt the data.

I want to ensure there are no obvious flaws in this scheme.

**Method**

*Note: every step below happens on the client side.*

Precursor:

1. Upon login/registration, generate global key `gk = SHA256(user_password)` and store *gk* in <strike>a cookie</strike> localStorage. *(The reason for this is to not store the user's password plainly.)*

Encrypting:

1. For every file, generate a random key *fk*.
2. Encrypt file with *fk*.
3. Encrypt *fk* with *gk* to get *fk'*.
4. Transmit encrypted file and *fk'* to server for storage.

Decrypting:

1. Receive encrypted file and *fk'* from server.
2. Decrypt *fk'* using *gk* to get *fk*.
3. Decrypt file using *fk*.

When user changes password:

1. For every file, decrypt *fk'* using current *gk* to get *fk*.
2. Generate new *gk* using new password.
3. Encrypt *fk* with new *gk* to get *fk'*.
4. Transmit new file *fk'* to server for storage.

When user forgets password:

1. Out of luck. (Unless?)

What flaws exist in this procedure?

**Update**

One flaw is that if the user authenticates login with a password, then technically, I can easily compute and store *gk* on the server, thus compromising the promise of client side encryption.

A solution to this:

1. Generate `pw = SHA256(SHA256(user_password))` and send this to the server as the user's password. The server then receives this password, and encrypts it again before storing it.

So as far as the server is concerned, it's just receiving a regular password. But this way, `gk` cannot be computed server side.

Flaws?

Comment: Since `gk` is stored in a cookie, it's also transmitted to the server - isn't this then enough for the server to decrypt the data?

Comment: @w3d The cookie is stored in the client browser. What makes you think the cookie is sent to the server?

Comment: @maq Browsers the send cookies to the server on every request.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize that. Then yeah, in localStorage.

Comment: 2 thoughts on the update: a) AgentMe is right, don't use sha256. It's much too fast for hashing passwords. b) I think you should make the master encryption key be independent of the authentication password you use with the server. Right now, if someone manages to steal the localstorage, he gets gk, which he can then hash to yield the login password. Once he has that, he can authenticate with your service.

Comment: @Pascal but if its not derived from the user's password, how can the user go on any computer and have the same master encryption key?

Comment: I'm not saying you shouldn't derive gk and pw from the user's password. But don't make it possible to derive pw from gk, which you store in localstorage. If the localstorage gets stolen, but pw can't be gotten from localstorage, then the files are still all safe on the server because they are not available to the attacker (even though he could decrypt them if he had access to them). In fact, if I were you and user experience allowed for it, I wouldn't store either gk or pw in localstorage at all, just keep them in browser memory and have the user reenter the password for each new session.

Comment: @Pascal I see what you're saying. How would I go about generating a master encryption key that's independent of the user's password? Would this require asking the user for an additional piece of data? Or is there some kind of manipulation I could employ with the data I already have (email and password)?

Comment: hmmm,  how about using a known, but individual random string m for each user and then calculate pw=hmac(user_password, m) ? Maybe send user-password  through bcrypt or scrypt beforehand.

Comment: @Pascal so is `m` generated on the server and sent to client before a registration request is made? Is it random based on the email, or totally random?

Comment: @Pascal wait a minute. Couldn't I just use a different hashing method for gk and pw to solve this issue? If gk=sha256(user_password) and is stored locally, and pw=sha128(user_password), then doesn't that solve the issue?

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect all this discussion going on in the comments.

Answer (score 5):

The biggest flaw in this scheme is that it depends on javascript code that will be transmitted to the client by the (a) server.

So, what's to keep the server (or a man in the middle) to send the client modified javascript that circumvents all the security measures? How would the client, or, for that matter, the user ever know? All the code that you write to check fingerprints, checksums, digital signatures etc can likewise be circumvented.

A related problem is other, malicious javascript code running in your Browser that can't be reliably isolated from your security-related javascript code.

This is impossible to fix. In-Browser Javascript is currently not a secure platform and all browser client-side cryptography suffers from this gaping security hole that can't be closed.

#### Summary of the discussion in the comments regarding the updated question

Calculating pw = sha256(sha256(user_password)) strikes me as a bad idea for several reasons.

1. The first one was already mentioned by AgentMe: Don't use simple hash
   functions such as sha-whatever to hash passwords. These hash functions were designed to be implemented efficiently in hardware and are much, much 
   too fast; to hash passwords, you want slow hash functions. See AgentMe's 
   answer.
2. With this scheme, pw can be calculated if you know gk (which is just sha256(user_password)). So when someone steals your localstorage, you give him access both to the master encryption key and to the authentication/authorization token he needs to download the encrypted files. It would be better to keep the two secrets independent of each other, so if one is compromised by a third party, it's not enough to calculate the other one and break the confidentiality of the encrypted data.
3. Finally, you're not salting your user_password with this scheme. This means that identical passwords across your whole userbase will yield identical hash values (and there are already large rainbow tables for unsalted sha-hashes out there containing the few million most common passwords).

You suggest an alternative, e.g. gk=sha256(user_password) and pw=sha128(user_password). While this solves point 2, it doesn't address 1 und 3. Also I wouldn't recommend it because I could imagine that this needlessly provides additional information to an attacker (the same password hashed to two different hash values), even though I don't know how to exploit it.

I suggested using gk=hmac(user_password, n) and pw=hmac(user_password, m), where m and n are known, but different for each user. How you arrive at m and n is irrelevant, as long as they're random and sufficiently large to make them unique across your user base with a high probability. You could create them on the client and submit them for storage at the server, indexed by the username so they can be retrieved on other clients. Or you can have the server generate them when the user first creates an account. The values don't need to be kept secure; they're worthless without the user_password. An improvement improvement would be to use  gk=hmac(bcrypt(user_password), n) and pw=hmac(bcrypt(user_password), m) to make brute force attacks harder.

Now, I'm not convinced that this suggestion is a good idea, since hmac is designed for message authentication, not for creating authentication tokens or encryption keys, so I'd take that suggestion with a grain of salt. But it seems to solve all three points I raise, so it seems like a better solution than chaining the same hash function or using two different hash functions on the password.

Comment: But if I did server side encryption, then the user will never be satisfied that their data was handled respectfully. And couldn't that same argument be made server side? What if my server was hacked and the unencrypted data was stored plainly? So if both have vulnerabilities, what makes server side encryption a better option?

Comment: Also, the client side vulnerability you mentioned puts the responsibility of safety on the user, and not myself, right? Whereas server side, the responsibility for safety would be mine.

Comment: The user can't be satisfied that you handled his data respectfully anyway, since there is no way for him to make sure that the server doesn't cheat. I'm not saying you shouldn't use client-side encryption, but you should be aware that your security model is broken before you start to implement it. You can't do it securely, no matter how hard you try, because the platform doesn't allow for it. The user has no choice but to trust the server.

Comment: And yes, getting malicious javascript executed in the browser is the user's fault. :-)

Comment: So then even LastPass is susceptible to this vulnerability? See part on Master Password https://lastpass.com/support.php?cmd=showfaq&id=6926. `No, when you login to LastPass, two things are generated from your Master Password using our code discussed previously before anything is sent to the server: the password hash and the decryption key. This is all done locally. `

Comment: Well, to be honest, ALL software is susceptible to this - you need to trust the software vendor not to add backdoors, phone home, handle your data responsibly etc. It's just much easier to break the security of in-browser javascript. LastPass offers browser plugins, which I think can be digitally signed at least in some browsers, so with them at least you run a much smaller risk of MITM attacks.

Comment: This issue of client side encryption aside, let me know if you have any thoughts on the edits.

Answer (score 1):

1. `gk` needs to be stored in localStorage/IndexedDB and not a cookie, because cookies get sent to the server!
2. You should use a stronger password hashing / key derivation algorithm than SHA256 which is more resistant to brute-force.
3. How does the user authenticate to the server? You probably don't want to let just any user request or update the encrypted `fk'` files for any other user. You'll want users to authenticate in a way besides sending their plaintext password. You could have them send the `gk` value put through the key derivation function a second time.
4. See https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/. You (or someone coercing you, or someone who has hacked you) can get user data by changing the javascript your server gives so that it sends the users' `gk` values back to the server or otherwise leaks them. This could be mitigated with good use of service workers that have openly-reviewed code but I'm not sure anyone has done that satisfactorily yet.

Comment: 2. which do you recommend?
3. The user authenticates through HTTPS connection to a regular Rails app. Is this sufficient?
4. Is this a flaw in my design or just a general issue? Are there better methods for me to explore?

Comment: 2. Any password hashing algorithm typically used for making password hashes on the server should work, like bcrypt. 3. But what does the user type to be authenticated? What does the server receive? If the user authenticates by typing and sending their password to the server as is usual for websites then the server will have their password and could decrypt their files.

Comment: The server receives their password to authenticate. You're right then, that seems to be a flaw in this design. Are there any simple edits I can make to this design that would fix this, or is this entire scheme bust?

Comment: `You could have them send the gk value put through the key derivation function a second time.`
Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Actually I think I get what you mean. See edits. Let me know if this works.